# Docker Desktop for Windows configure to use Proxy Auto-Config Script (PAC)

Tags: docker, proxy, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I am using windows **10 Enterprise Version 1607**,

We use a Proxy Auto Config (PAC) script for Proxy config.

The problem is docker connectivity. I have Docker **17.12.0-ce** (stable release) is installed. I'm not able to configure Docker to use PAC to pull docker registry images.

Kindly help! I've gone through the official documentation several times, but nothing helpful. I'm not sure if I'm missing something.

Comment: This may be new since this question was asked - according to docker docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/settings/windows/#proxies): "If the host uses a HTTP/HTTPS proxy configuration (static or via **Proxy Auto-Configuration**), Docker Desktop reads this configuration and **automatically** uses these settings for logging into Docker, **for pulling and pushing images**, and for container Internet access."

Answer (score -1):

.pac configuration file is actually returning a proxy server address based on which url you are visiting.
So you can skip using .pac and set your HTTP PROXY directly to docker.

If you want to know what is your proxy server address, visit the .pac from your browser, read it and you will find the proxy server address in clear text there.

Comment: in general a pac file can return different proxy and even direct based on the address / domain.